# Why checkbox checked if database (MySQL) value is 0 in Livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have been trying to view whether the checkbox is checked (value: Add customer) or unchecked ( value: 0) based on the database value. But the checkbox show checked  when the database (MySQL) value is 0 in Livewire.

```
    "change_metadata1"=>$this->change_metadata1,
    "change_metadata2"=>$this->change_metadata2,
    "change_metadata3"=>$this->change_metadata3,
    "change_metadata4"=>$this->change_metadata4,
    "change_metadata5"=>$this->change_metadata5,
    "change_metadata6"=>$this->change_metadata6,
```

Customer name
                                
 
      Customer address

```
                            <label for="change_metadata">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="standards" value="Scope" wire:model="change_metadata3"> Scope
                            </label>

                            <label for="change_metadata">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="standards" value="New contact" wire:model="change_metadata4"> New contact
                            </label>

                            <label for="change_metadata">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="standards" value="Number of employees" wire:model="change_metadata5"> Number of employees
                            </label>

                            <label for="change_metadata">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="standards" value="New decision" wire:model="change_metadata6"> New decision
                            </label>
```

Comment: `change_...`  is not defined as a variable `public change_...`  , did you added inside an array?, if yes you could try `wire:model="array['change_...']"` , never tried an array insied of a wire:model maybe it will work

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: $this-> change_metadata1 = $customer->change_metadata1 ?: false;